# dice probability, n dice greater than or equal to m value out of z total dice

Tags: java, combinatorics

I've been working on a small function to calculate the probabilities of getting m values greater than or equal to x when rolling n different dice.  So far I have

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class DiceProbabilityCalculator {
    private static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> dice = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

        int numberOfDice = 2;
        int numberOfSuccess = 1;
        for (int check = 1, max = dice.size(); check <= max; ++ check) {
            int pass = max - check + 1;
            int failure = check - 1;

            double probPass = prob(pass, max);
            double probFail = prob(failure, max);
            double result = choose(numberOfDice, numberOfSuccess) * Math.pow(probPass, numberOfSuccess) * Math.pow(probFail, numberOfDice - numberOfSuccess);

            System.out.println(
                    "dice count: " + numberOfDice +
                    ", dice equal or greater than threshold: " + numberOfSuccess +
                    ", success threshold: " + check +
                    ", result: " + df.format(result)
            );
        }
    }

    static double prob(int countValue, int maxValue) {
        return (1.0 * countValue)/(1.0 * maxValue);
    }

    static double choose(int n, int k) {
        return (factorial(n) / (factorial(n-k)*factorial(k)));
    }

    static double factorial(int num) {
        if (num >= 1)
            return num * factorial(num - 1);
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

The result seems correct for the case where the number of dice match the number of successes, but if there are less successes, I am getting an invalid number.

It's been a minute since I've taken any statistics classes and I am not sure what I am forgetting.

The results for the are:

```
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 1, result: 0.0000
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 2, result: 0.2778
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 3, result: 0.4444
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 4, result: 0.5000
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 5, result: 0.4444
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 6, result: 0.2778
```

When I have 2 dice, and am want 1 of them to meet the criteria, I get a probability of zero when I should have a probability of 1.  Also the probability of getting a single result is smaller when rolling two dice instead of one (that isn't right).

**Solution:**

I updated the result to look like the following:

```
double result = 0;
for (int itr = numberOfSuccess; itr <= numberOfDice; ++itr) {
    result += choose(numberOfDice, itr) * pow(probPass, itr) * pow(probFail, numberOfDice - itr);
}
```

this gave me results that looked more correct.

```
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 1, result: 1.0000
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 2, result: 0.9722
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 3, result: 0.8889
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 4, result: 0.7500
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 5, result: 0.5556
dice count: 2, dice equal or greater than threshold: 1, success threshold: 6, result: 0.3056
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: added the helper methods, should be able to copy, paste, compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the cases where you get more passes than you need to beat the check. In the case that you've marked with the question marks, for example, both dice always succeed, which means that you never get exactly one success, hence your code reports probability 0.

If using someone else's program to calculate these numbers is an option, [Troll](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/%7Etorbenm/Troll/) might work for you.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  I am trying to wrap my head around what the equation should look like.  Do I need to add nCr where r = numberOfSuccess + x, where x represents an incrementing number until numOfDice is reached?

Comment: @SethHays yes, that would do it.

Comment: I added the following

for (int itr = numberOfSuccess; itr <= numberOfDice; ++itr) {
                        result += choose(numberOfDice, itr) * pow(probPass, itr) * pow(probFail, numberOfDice - itr);
                    }

and got results that look more correct